# Eclipse 3.7 Unresolved Gradle Dependency errors

Tags: java, javafx-2, gradle, eclipse-indigo, build-dependencies

Eclipse info.,

- Version:  Indigo Service Release 2
- Build id: 20120216-1857

And here's a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjXj5.png) to the resulting "Problems" view  tab. And I've tried refreshing the Gradle Dependencies, but it's not resolving the errors. And I have JavaFX 2.1 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the "unresolved gradle dependency" error.

### Problem?

`JAVAFX_HOME` environmental variable was missing.

### Solution

1. Add `JAVAFX_HOME` environmental variable with the path `%YOUR_INSTALL_PATH%\JavaFX 2.1 Runtime`.
2. Reboot machine
3. Open project in IDE (e.g. Eclipse)
4. Refresh gradle dependencies

Answer (score 0):

The error means that a dependency declared in the build script could not be resolved. In other words, the dependency could not be found in any of the repositories declared in the build script. `gradle dependencies` should give a similar error.